# MS SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016

Is DB Online Index Rebuild supported by MS SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. It is only supported for **Enterprise Edition** in 2016. Please see the [**Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016 - RDBMS High Availability**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSHA) table for more information.